# Mongo: Looking for the fastest query for collection of millions of instances

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a collection of millions of instances of this simple object:

```
{
 Org: string,
 Value: string
}
```

There is a secondary index by `[Org]` field, and there are around thousand of different `[Org]` values. This collection is not supposed to be updated as it's filled in once at a time.

Now I have a task: request `[Value]` values for the specific `[Org]` in the natural order (the order they were inserted into database, i.e. `$orderby: _id`), and limited by specific number, with maximum performance. My questions are:

- Does order of operators like `orderby`, `query`, `limit` and `sort` impact performance and execution plan in the case?
- Will both indexes (secondary by `[Org]` and default primary by `_id`) will be used in the query?
- Is there any tool for MongoDb to trace indexes usage like Query Analyzer for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `explain()` to see how your queries are using indexes. You can see which index you're using by the "cursor" returned, and some key stats are `nscanned`, `n`, `scanAndOrder`, and `millis`.

One key thing to note, is that mongodb can only use one index per query.

Yes, sort will impact performance. In order to use sort with a query, you should have an index with the last field(s) in the index the field(s) you want to sort on. So, you could make an index on `{org:1, _id:1}`, in order to optimize the query and the sort. You'll note that `scanAndOrder` will be false after that.

Update: Forgot to mention `limit`. `limit` will usually improve your performance, because you give mongo a chance to cut its search short. It helps if you `limit` while you're sorting on an indexed field, otherwise it has to scan all of the results before returning the ones you're looking for.